# "extension.LiveServer.goOnline" not found and 'liveSass.command.watchMySass' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I installed the Live Sass Compile I got this error message when trying to use them.

Command "extension.LiveServer.goOnline" not found
Command 'liveSass.command.watchMySass' not found

May someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

go to your c disk ->users->adminfolder->.vscode->extensions ->  delete the liveserver folder. After that go to vscode editor and install the live server extension.
It will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to here : `C:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions`

Delete this folder : `ritwickdey.liveserver-5.7.5`

and install Live Server again.